# reload 2 or more website and click on specify buttons on this website

Tags: javascript, ejs

I´m looking for a way to create a program that reloads any two websites and then clicks on a specifc div-button on both websites. Any idea?

```
<script>
setTimout(function(){
window.location.reload(1);
},3000);
```

It could be best if I can get the answere for .pug or .ejs with Javascript.

Thank you

Comment: I think I can help you with this. Any two websites? Or a specific set? Because not all websites can be placed inside an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), which would be the way to go to achieve this.

Comment: https://freebitco.in/?op=home and https://freedoge.co.in/?op=home

for example

Many times I don´t need to make recaptcha

Comment: Thanks man, I was thinking of [frebitcoin](https://freebitco.in/?op=home) or / and [moondoge](http://moondoge.co.in/) like thouse websites